# Properties of an Operator and its Square

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Suppose I have an arbritrary operator $\hat{T}$ such that its square satisfies the eigenvalue equation
$$
\hat{T}^2 |\lambda\rangle = \lambda^2 |\lambda\rangle
$$
Is it always that this implies
$$
\hat{T} |\lambda\rangle = \lambda |\lambda\rangle
$$

Comment: No. This is not true in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. As a simple counterexample, let $\hat T$ denote the operator over $\Bbb C^2$ associated with the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}
$$
and the vector $v = (1,1) \in \Bbb C^2$. We have $A^2 v = 1^2\cdot v$, but $Av \neq 1 \cdot v$.

Answer (score 3):

Edit, Per Arturo Magidin's comment :
For a Real counterexample, consider $R$ as a rotation by $\pi/2$ in the plane , so that $R^2$ is a rotation by $\pi$ with eigenvalues $\{-1 \}$ ( multiplicity $2$)  , while $R$, being a rotation by $\pi/2$ gives us:

$$
R = \pmatrix{\cos \pi/2& \sin \pi/2\\ -\sin \pi/2& \cos \pi/2}=\pmatrix{0 &  1 \\ -1 & 0}
$$

Doesn't even have Real eigenvalues, its characteristic polynomial being $ \lambda^2+1$.

Comment: @ Arturo magidin : Thank you, editing. I did use both \sin ad \cos.

Comment: Really, you should fix *everything*, not just pieces.

Comment: No, the eigenvalues of $R^2$ are $-1$, not $1$... Sigh. You really need to be much more careful when answering. You are lucky you haven't been downvoted for persistent silly errors.

Comment: You're right. Hopefully all OK by now. Thanks for suggestions/corrections and patience.   Will be more careful from now on.